# Connect java to SQL server with jdbc dirver

Tags: java, sql-server

I have read another topics connected to it and didn't find the solution,

```
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://;server_name=MYSERVERNAME,instancename=MAINSTANCENAME:1211;databaseName=MYDATABASENAME;user=MYUSER;password=MYPASSWORD";         
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);

        System.out.println("successfull");
```

the result is and error: `Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://;...`

in pom thera are dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1.jre10-preview</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: That adds the JDBC driver to your unit tests. Are you running unit tests in the above code?

Comment: no I dont ride Unit test yet.

Comment: What is the Class that you are importing using ```Class.forName``` ?

Comment: `Class.forName`???

Comment: Try removing the semicolon after ```//;```

Comment: `Class.forName` has been superfluous since (I believe) Java 6, which is 12 years old. The problem is that you added the JDBC driver as a test dependency, which means that it is only available during unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

From this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.1.jre10-preview</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

remove this line:

```
    <scope>test</scope>
```

It makes the JDBC driver only available during unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Create datasource bean:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://MYSERVERNAME;databaseName=MYDATABASENAME");
    dataSource.setUsername("MYUSER");
    dataSource.setPassword("MYPASSWORD");
    return dataSource;
}
```

And use it:

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("dataSource");
Connection c = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: what is `ApplicationContextProvider` ?

Comment: explanation herer: https://crazygui.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/get-to-spring-applicationcontext-from-everywhere-the-clean-way/

Comment: I did `SpringApplication.run(TestJdbcApplication.class, args).getBean("dataSource")` and your solution works... So what is wrong with my basic?

Comment: Semicolon in "jdbc:sqlserver://;"